# ¿Cómo descomprimir imagen con LZRW1 al vuelo?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, delphi

Tengo una imagen comprimida guardada en la **BD SQL SERVER**; la imagen fue comprimida usando [LZRW1](http://ross.net/compression/lzrw1.html) desde una aplicación hecha en ***Delphi***. El problema es que necesito cargar la imagen en una aplicación escrita en ***c#*** pero, como está comprimida la imagen, antes de visualizarla hay que descomprimirla.

¿Saben de algo que sea compatible con **LZRW1** para descomprimir?

He intentado con **GZipStream** en ***c#***, pero no es compatible con **LZRW1**.

Comment: no te compliques tanto, decomprímelas con tu aplicación en Delphi y vuélvelas a comprimir con un algoritmo más popular y actual como ser zip, rar, 7z. En caso de que no quieras hacer eso puedes empezar a desarrollar tu librería de compresión LZRW1 buscando documentación sobre el algoritmo en sí tal vez puedas empezar con un poco de historia. https://ethw.org/History_of_Lossless_Data_Compression_Algorithms

Comment: Desafortunadamente LZRW1 no es un algoritmo popular en estos días. Para descomprimir la imagen al vuelo, otra alternativa que puedes tomar es crear una DLL en Delphi (nativa) con una función para descomprimir un arreglo de bytes y luego invocar dicha DLL desde tu código de c#.

Comment: Muchas gracias  jachguate en eso mismo estoy ahora, no hay otra alternativa, gracias por los demas comentarios, pero no me queda de otra que crear una dll que haga esto, pues el codigo que comprime las imagenes con LZRW1 no podemos modificarlo ni comprimir con otro algoritmo

Answer (score 2):

La otra opción es directamente usar un formato de imagen comprimido (que para eso existen).

Porqué comprimir una imagen en formato ZIP o RAR cuando las propias imágenes poseen formatos que incluyen compresión y el resultado sigue siendo una imagen?

Por ejemplo, una imagen **PNG** de **177Kb** al comprimirla a **ZIP** pasa a tener **176Kb** (se puede probar con cualquier otra que tengáis en vuestro equipo). En este caso, la ganacia (si la hay) no compensa el proceso de compresión/descompresión.

Por lo tanto, si tienes acceso al código del programa Delphi, yo te recomiendo que cambies a compresión de la imagen a un formato de compresión de imágenes (sea con pérdida o sin pérdida de calidad, eso ya depende de las necesidades).